# Count remaining items

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB where I am storing INQUIRIES (messages from people) and another where I have CATEGORIES for these inquiries that can be applied (like flagging a message).

I have an SQL snippet that looks like this:

```
select ic.name, count(i.id) as usage_count from inquiry i
inner join inquiry_category ic on ic.id = i.category
group by ic.name
order by usage_count desc
```

That give the following results:

```
Water 6
Electricity 2
```

...and so on. Basically, I am getting the number of times an inquiry category has been applied.

Now, I want a counter for the times it has NOT been applied (uncategorised inquiries) as well. How would I add that to the query? BTW, inquiry.category = 0 means that no category has been applied so that is what would be worked with.

Also, would be nice if that always ended up as the FIRST result.

/Robert

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected result out of those sample data, best is on http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 2):

That's possible with standard `LEFT JOIN`, don't need to use `UNION`

```
SELECT IF(ic.name IS NOT NULL, ic.name, 'Uncategoried') as name. count(i.id) as usage_count 
 FROM inquiry i
 LEFT JOIN inquiry_category ic ON ic.id = i.category
 GROUP BY ic.name
 ORDER BY usage_count desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, cracked it. Did the following:

```
select 'Uncategorized' as name, count(i.id) as usage_count from inquiry i where i.category = 0

union all

select ic.name, count(i.id) as usage_count from inquiry i
inner join inquiry_category ic on ic.id = i.category
group by ic.name
order by usage_count desc
```

Works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select CASE WHEN ic.name IS NULL THEN 'Uncategorized' ELSE ic.name END as category_name, count(i.id) as usage_count from inquiry i
leftjoin inquiry_category ic on ic.id = i.category
group by category_name
order by usage_count desc
```